# CSS3 color transition on hover, but on click have immediate color change

Tags: css

I have coded my page so that when the cursor hovers over the link, it changes color gradually via CSS3. I want it so that when it is clicked, it changes immediately to another color. How can I do this?

```
.menuButton {
    color: #888;
}
.menuButton:hover {
    color: black;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.7s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: color 0.7s ease-in;
    -o-transition: color 0.7s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: color 0.7s ease-in;
    transition: color 0.7s ease-in;
}
.menuButton:active {
    color: #880000;
}
```

Comment: You don't need all those prefixes improve your code just adding the necessary http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `transition-property:none;`

```
.menuButton:active {
    color: #880000;
    -webkit-transition-property: none;
    -moz-transition-property: none;
    -o-transition-property: none;
    -ms-transition-property: none;
    transition-property: none;
}
```

Comment: There's also: [`transition-duration: 0;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-duration).